# Reload DataTable with new JSON data not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a DataTable with data, and also have a date filter for it. When I request data with filter values relevant data comes according to the filter. And I want to update the DataTable according to that filtered data. I tried a lot of codes, but nothing works for me.

My Code:

```js
          $('#pending-appointments-daterange').daterangepicker({
              opens: 'right', 
              showWeekNumbers: true
            }, function(start, end, label) {

              $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/get_pending_appointments',
                data: {
                  from: start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                  to: end.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                }
              })
              .done(function(res) {
                //$('#pending-appointments-datatable').DataTable().destroy();
                //$('#pending-appointments-datatable').DataTable().clear()
                //$('#pending-appointments-datatable').DataTable().ajax.json() = res.dataTableData
                //$('#pending-appointments-datatable').DataTable().clear().draw();
                //$('#pending-appointments-datatable').DataTable().draw();

               $('#pending-appointments-datatable').DataTable().clear().draw();

                //console.log(res)
                //$('#pending-appointments-datatable').url(res).load();
                //$('#pending-appointments-datatable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
              })
              .fail(function(err) {
                console.log(err)
              });

            });
```

How can I reload the datatable with filtered data ? plz help me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the existing rows and then add the rows again if res is your array of items.

```js
          $('#pending-appointments-daterange').daterangepicker({
              opens: 'right', 
              showWeekNumbers: true
            }, function(start, end, label) {

              $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/get_pending_appointments',
                data: {
                  from: start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                  to: end.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                }
              })
              .done(function(res) {

                $('#pending-appointments-datatable').DataTable().clear();
                $('#pending-appointments-datatable').DataTable().rows.add(res);
                $('#pending-appointments-datatable').DataTable().draw();

                //console.log(res)
                //$('#pending-appointments-datatable').url(res).load();
                //$('#pending-appointments-datatable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
              })
              .fail(function(err) {
                console.log(err)
              });

            });
```

Comment: i get JSON as res from backend, how can I convert as array?

Comment: please provide an example